# Are the locked funds in a contract still considered as delegated to a wallet and can get staking rewards?

Tags: smart-contract

The question here is if script-locked outputs can still have a staking key associated with them  (decided by the person creating the output) and whether this enables the funds to be delegated in a contract to get staking rewards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it will be possible to associate a staking address for script outputs.